# Retrieve string from AudioRecord buffer

Tags: android, buffer, basic4android, audiorecord

I'm using Basic4Android and the AudioRecord library that is based on [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html)

I want to know how to retrieve a string from buffer

In short, if you register with audiorecord a word (eg, "hello"), you can retrieve this from the buffer in order to have a string value "hello"?

Thanks
Alberto

Comment: does AudioRecord convert speech to string?

Answer (score 1):

With just audiorecord library I don't think you can get a speech recognition, as far as I know you get raw sound wave from there, but try with [SpeechRecognizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html),
a demo application tutorial [here](http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/android-how-to-implement-voice-recognition-a-nice-easy-tutorial/)

Comment: thanks, but with SpeechRecognizer is need to start the recognizer and listens for a given time. my goal is to run a service in background that listens continuously

Comment: @AlbertoRubini wow, that sounds really tough...in bocca al lupo!

Answer (score 0):

i am glad to see other use basic 4 android too you'll find several libraries here
https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/pages/results/?query=speech+recognizer

and here is what seems to be the answer:
https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/another-speechrecognizer-library.37584/#content